# My computer automatically installs windows updates even though i have disabled the automatic install option, why?

Tags: windows, updates, automatic-update

I have disabled the automatic update installation feature for windows 10 on my laptop through the update settings because my computer installs them and restarts every time i turn it on. Instead i have selected the option in which the computer should send me a notification about updates then give me the option to install them. However, it continues to automatically install these updates, restarting my computer every time. The only noticeable change is that after the update downloads it tells me that it could not complete the updates and gets stuck in a loop. Any suggestions

Comment: Try disabling Windows Update and Background Intelligent Transfer Service services and setting their startup types to Manual.

Comment: If set to manual Windows will just turn them on...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot permanently disable Windows 10 Updates on individual (OEM Licensed) machines. Windows will just turn them back on.

Go to Start, Settings, Windows Updates, and use the Pause, Change Active Hours, and Advanced Settings to Manage Updates. You can pause Updates for a month thereabouts and stick handle around the vast majority of situations.

Managing Updates is a better way to go and does work.

Comment: Well you can, but requires a 3rd party software to do it, I have done this on all my W10 machines.

Comment: Over time Feature Updates usually turn updates back on. That has been my experience.

Comment: Haven't had that happen on 4 machines using WUMT utility across many feature updates.